# Orchard Element Alternates

Tags: c#, orchardcms

We have couple of Elements hosted on a Module . and we have couple of themes .

each Element already include some alternates . deciding which one to render is done by the `DisplayType` on the `ElementDriver` Editor result  .

example : MyElement-Xtype is an alternate of MyElement with the display type Xtype .

we want to move all our templates of Elements on the Elements Folder (Views/Element) .

to the Template View Folder .

so we want to make the Element Driver looks for the template in `MyTheme/Views/Elements` instead of `MyModule/Views/Elements` .

Why ? why not just include the elements to the theme ?

cause the element will be shared between themes . so when a theme is activated it will take the **view of the current Theme**

> how can i Achieve this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured it out since i tried it but it didn't work . cause my theme was not enabled . this is already configured . Orchard will take the Element template in the Module If the template on the theme does not exist .

its good to speak your problems tho .